# IS there a way to Execute Dataloader from Flows

Tags: apex, trigger, ftp, dataloader.io

Im in the need to mas update/create Accounts from a CSV file but i need to schedule it. The   i was wondering if there is a way to build a FLOW on Salesforce that executes dataloader with  setted confingurations and do the upsert of saids accounts.

IF not, i ask you if there is another way, such as building a Flow or Apex to read that file from an Stp/ftp and replicate the data import done by the DataLoader

Regards.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please taka a moment to read about [ask] and take our short [tour]. This is what we call an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info), because you're trying to do something that isn't possible, without telling us specifically what your end goal is. Where is the CSV coming from? Is there another way you can source the data other than FTP/SFTP? Be as detailed as you need to be; the better we understand your business requirement, the better we can help identify an appropriate solution. You can [edit] your question to provide all the detail you need.

Answer (score 0):

From Apex STP/FTP connection is not possible. Your use case more appropriate for using Salesforce Functions where you schedule the call to functions which will read your file and send/upsert back in Salesforce.
Other solution is to custom build a page to parse the csv in apex and perform DML.